# Window Dimensions on Windows

Tags: windows, window, dimensions

How do I get the width and height of a window? Let's say I, an end user, open Chrome in a window, and then resize it. How can I, an end user, find out how large the window is now? Chrome is just an example; I am looking for how to do this with any application in a window.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a simple tool like [WinSpy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/winspyex/) or the Window Spy tool included in the [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/download/) package.

Comment: +1, I was already using AutoHotKey but didn't know about Window Spy.

Answer (score 3):

You can make your own

Copy following two files to a folder.

**To Use**:

```
GetWindowRect <Title Of Window>
```

EG

```
GetWindowRect Untitled - Notepad
```

---

Change `/target:exe` to `/target:winexe` to make it a non console program

```
REM GetWindowRect.bat
REM This file compiles GetWindowRect.vb to GetWindowRect.exe
REM GetWindowRect.exe reports on Windows position
REM To use 
REM GetWindowRect 
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe" /target:exe /out:"%~dp0\GetWindowRect.exe" "%~dp0\GetWindowRect.vb"
pause
```

---

```
;GetWindowRect.vb
imports System.Runtime.InteropServices 
Public Module GetWindowRect  

     <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Private Structure RECTL     
        Public Left As UInt32
        Public Top As UInt32
        Public Right As UInt32
        Public Bottom As UInt32
    End Structure

    Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "User32" (ByVal hWnd as IntPtr, ByRef Rect as RectL) as Integer
    Public Declare UNICODE Function FindWindowW Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr

    Sub Main
        On Error Resume Next
        Dim hWindows as IntPtr
        Dim Ret as Integer
        hwindows = FindWindowW(vbNullString, Command())
        If hwindows = 0 then
            Msgbox(Command() & " cannot be found.")
        Else
            Dim x as RectL
            Ret = GetWindowRect(hWindows, x)
            If Ret = 0 Then 
                MsgBox("GetWindowRect Error " & Err.LastDllError)
            Else
            'Delete the MsgBox line if using as console program
            Msgbox(x.left & " " & x.top & " " & x.right & " " & x.bottom)
            Console.Writeline(x.left & " " & x.top & " " & x.right & " " & x.bottom)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

---

Also available here - https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/01/getwindowrectexe-reports-on-windows.html

Comment: Great, the main thing to do is use the [`GetWindowRect`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) function! If you have python and `pywin32` installed and you don't want a VBScript, you can do it with a small python script: `import win32gui` `h = win32gui.FindWindow(None, input("Name of window: "))` `if not h: print("Window not found!")` `else:` `left, top, right, bottom = win32gui.GetWindowRect(a)` `width, height = (right - left), (bottom - top)` `print(f'{left=}\n{right=}\n{width=}\n{height=}')` (modified as you want)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Snipping Tool to capture a screenshot of the window, and then look at the properties of the screenshot to see the dimensions of the window.

Answer (score 2):

My fastest way :

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>
- Open paint and reduce Canvas
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

The size of the window is in the status bar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: expanded answer a bit to improve clarity.